# How to display all x labels in R barplot?

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart, axis-labels

This is a basic question but I am unable to find an answer. I am generating about 9 barplots within one panel and each barplot has about 12 bars. I am providing all the 12 labels in my input but R is naming only alternate bars. This is obviously due to to some default setting in R which needs to be changed but I am unable to find it.

Comment: Make the plotting canvas larger

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You may be able get all of the labels to appear if you use `las=2` inside the `plot()` call. This argument and the others mentioned below are described in `?par` which sets the graphical parameters for plotting devices. That rotates the text 90 degrees. Otherwise, you will need to use `xaxt="n"` (to suppress ticks and labels) and then put the labels in with a separate call to `axis(1, at= <some numerical vector>, labels=<some character vector>)`.

```
#  midpts <- barplot( ... ) # assign result to named object
axis(1, at = midpts, labels=names(DD), cex.axis=0.7) # shrinks axis labels
```

Another method is to first collect the midpoints and then use `text()` with `xpd`=TRUE to allow text to appear outside the plot area and `srt` be some angle for text rotation as named arguments to control the degree of text rotation:

```
text(x=midpts, y=-2, names(DD), cex=0.8, srt=45, xpd=TRUE)
```

The y-value needs to be chosen using the coordinates in the plotted area.

Copying a useful comment: For future readers who don't know what these arguments do: las=2 rotates the labels counterclockwise by 90 degrees. furthermore, if you need to reduce the font you can use cex.names=.5 to shrink the size down

Comment: las=2, works fine and is especially more useful with so many bars

Comment: The `las=2` suggestion works, but `axis(...)` doesn't. `axis()` is what's being used by `barplot()` in the first place; when called on its own, it'll again 'try hard not to draw overlapping tick labels', (as `?axis` put it).

Comment: It does depend on the particular case. In the case you offered this code does add labels at each tick: `axis(1, at = midpts, labels=names(DD), cex.axis=0.7)`

Comment: to clarify for future readers who don't know what these arguments do: las=2 rotates the labels counterclockwise by 90 degrees.  furthermore, if you need to reduce the font you can use cex.names=.5 to shrink the size down

Comment: Is there an easy way to calculate `midpts`?

Comment: @ms609 The object returned by `barplot` (if you assign it rather than just using it for its side-effect of plotting) is a vector or matrix with the midpoint values. I assumed it was named  `midpts`, but any name would do. For a bit more information read `?barplot` with focus on the 'Value' section.

Answer (score 18):

To get rotated labels on a base R barplot, you could (like I do here) adapt one of the
examples given in the vignette of the **gridBase** package:

```
library(grid)
library(gridBase)

## Make some data with names long enough that barplot won't print them all
DD <- table(rpois(100, lambda=5))
names(DD) <- paste("long", names(DD), sep="_")

## Plot, but suppress the labels
midpts <- barplot(DD, col=rainbow(20), names.arg="")

## Use grid to add the labels    
vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)

grid.text(names(DD),
    x = unit(midpts, "native"), y=unit(-1, "lines"),
    just="right", rot=50)

popViewport(3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm. I just get "could not find function "pushViewport" so I guess this is old

Comment: @Dirk Thanks for the comment Looks like you now need to explicitly load the **grid** package. I just made that edit, and it now works as intended.

Answer (score 9):

R won't label every bar if the labels are too big.

I would suggest trying to rotate the labels vertically by passing in the las=2 argument to your plotting function.

If the labels are still too large, you can try shrinking the font by using the cex.names=.5 argument.

Sample Data for plot

```
sample_curve <- c(2.31,2.34,2.37,2.52,2.69,2.81,2.83,2.85,2.94, 3.03,  3.21,  3.33)   # create a sample curve
names(sample_curve)<-c("1 MO","2 MO","3 MO","6 MO","1 YR","2 YR","3 YR","5 YR","7 YR","10 YR","20 YR","30 YR") # label the curve
```

Example of plot with labels too big

```
barplot(sample_curve) # labels too big for the plot
```

[image: labels too big]

Example of plot with labels rotated and small

```
barplot(sample_curve, las=2, cex.names=.5) # lables are rotated and smaller, so they fit
```

[image: rotated and smaller]

Answer (score 2):

before plotting the `barplot()`

You can simply increase the margins with `par()` and your margins values (your plot has 4 margins) `mar = c(v1,v2,v3,V4)`

```
par(mar=c(10,4,4,4))
```

as example :

```
par(mar=c(10,4,4,4))
barplot(height=c(1,5,8,19,7),
        names.arg=c("very long label 1","very long label 2",
                    "very long label 3","very long label 4",
                    "very long label 5"), las=2 )
```

[image: Very long labels Barplot]