# X axis does not match barplot

Tags: r, plot

I used barplot() function to create a stacked chart from matrix.

Matrix looks like this:

```
1 0.989013 0.010987
2 0.999990 0.000010
3 0.999990 0.000010
4 0.999990 0.000010
```

code to create a stacked chart looks like this:

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(x)), col=c("cyan", "black"))
```

The problem is that I want to create custom x axis with ticks and labels at certain points. I used following to create x axis:

```
axis(1, at=keyindexes, labels=unique(t$V4), tck=-0.01)
```

where keyindexes is vector of bar numbers where I need to have ticks and unique(t$V4) is vector containing unique name for each tick.

Now the problem is that x axis does not match with chart area and is significantly shorter. Can anyone advice on how to make x axis longer?

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible, for starters by posting the result of `dput(x)`?

Comment: You could post `dput(head(x, 30))` or something similar

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem with axis labels is in fact that bars are not centered on whole numbers.
For example, make some data with ten rows and plot them with `barplot()`. Then add `axis()` for x axis at numbers from 1 to 10.

```
set.seed(1)
x<-data.frame(v1=rnorm(10),v2=rnorm(10))
barplot(t(as.matrix(x)), col=c("cyan", "black"))
axis(1,at=1:10)
```

[image]

Now axis texts are not in right position.

To correct this problem, `barplot()` should be saved as object and this object should be used as `at=` values in axis.

```
m<-barplot(t(as.matrix(x)), col=c("cyan", "black"))
m
 [1]  0.7  1.9  3.1  4.3  5.5  6.7  7.9  9.1 10.3 11.5
axis(1, at=m,labels=1:10)
```

[image]

### EDIT - plotting only some ticks

If only some of axis ticks texts should be plotted then you can subset `m` values that are needed and provided the same length of `labels=`. In this example only 1., 5. and 10. bars are annotated.

```
m<-barplot(t(as.matrix(x)), col=c("cyan", "black"))
lab<-c("A","B","C")
axis(1, at=m[c(1,5,10)],labels=lab)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. The problem is that I need to show custom labels and ticks on X axis. That's why I gave a vector with sample/row number to _axis(at)_ parameter. I need ticks on 1, 15, 34, 38 and so on. 35 strictly specified ticks in total, across all 576 samples, gap between ticks vary greatly. So I can put a label with sample name on each tick, I used _label_ argument to specify label for each tick and gave it a vector with labels. Maybe there are other ways to do that instead of messing around with axis() function.

Comment: Maybe also this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981929/how-to-display-all-x-labels-in-r-barplot

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `updateusr` function in the TeachingDemos package.  This function will change or "update" the user coordinates of a plot.  The example shows changing the coordinates of the x axis of a barplot to match the intuitive values for additional plotting.