# R barplot(): shifts over x-axis?

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot the PMF of binomial(40, 0.5), but the following `barplot` seems giving me a wrong x-axis position?

```
probability = dbinom(0:40, 40, 0.5)
plot(probability, pch = 21, bg="red")
barplot(probability, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

My `barplot()` is using the same data `probability` as its height, why it shifts a little bit toward right? I am wondering where I have missed and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15332146/6455166 should be helpful.

Comment: you can see the midpoints of the bars using `b = barplot(probability,  plot=FALSE, width=1, space=0)` (note I added the extra `width` and `space` arguments). Your scatter plot uses x-axis values from one to `length(probability)` by default as you didnt add in an x-variable. So you need to adjust this term.