# x-axis of barplot as custom time intervals

Tags: r, plot

I have data like this:

```
Day Hour Minute   averagespeed   
1    0    14       55
1    0    29       65
1    0    44       70  
1    0    59       55 
1    1    14       32
1    1    29       50
1    1    44       96
1    1    59       54
1    2    14       64
1    2    29       70
```

I want to plot this data as bar chart or histogram but the x axis is in hours from 0 to 23 and divided into 4 intervals of 15 minute intervals like this :

```
0 14 29 44 59 1 14 29 44 59 2 14 29 44 59 ..............23
```

against `averagespeed` for the y axis.

this data is for 30 days and I do not know how to make the x axis like that based on my columns shown above.

Comment: Please provide your data in an easy-to-paste form. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on how to do that. What have you tried so far and where you fail?

Comment: This axis choice seems like a bad choice. First, the intervals at not even. The gaps in minutes will repeat `14, 15 15, 15, 1, 14, 15, 15,15, 1,...`. Next, you are asking to put 120 labels on the time axis. That is going to be crowded and hard to read. Why not just put the hours?  You can still plot the points in between; just don't label every point.

Comment: Are you asking to plot 30 * 24 * 4 = 2880 points on a single graph?

Comment: No , 24*4 =96 points as a single graph for one day t .and then I plot 30 graphs for 30 days in one month.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define your own labels and custom x-axis. One additional difficulty is that by default the labels of such an axis do not align properly with `barplot` (but do with regular `plot`).

So you have to use the below workaround, saving the barplot as an object to then force the position of the x labels:

```
mylabels <- paste0(df$Hour, "h", df$Minute,"min")
# labels not aligned ------------------------------------------------------
#barplot(df$averagespeed, xaxt = "n", xlab="Time")
#axis(1, at=1:length(df$averagespeed), labels=mylabels)
# labels are aligned ------------------------------------------------------
m<-barplot(df$averagespeed, xaxt = "n", xlab="Time")
m
axis(1, at=m,labels=mylabels)
```

[image]
The creation of an x-axis is explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5182416/5224236

The workaround for barplots here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15332146/5224236